# How to handle JSON unstructured data using ng-for in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Array of JSON like

```
[
    { "name":"name1", "age": 21 },
    { "name":"name1", "age": 21 },
    { "age": 21 },
    { "name":"name1", "age": 21 },
    { "name":"name1", "age": 21 },
]
```

I'm binding that data using ngFor

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of data">
    <li>{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

and now getting an error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". How to get the proper output?

Comment: The code you are showing us, works perfectly.

Comment: Please show how you are obtaining the data. May be it is coming through observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let data = [
    { "name":"name1", "age": 21 },
    { "name":"name1", "age": 21 },
    { "age": 21 },
    { "name":"name1", "age": 21 },
    { "name":"name1", "age": 21 },
]
```

In your data array third object doesn't have the name parameter, so it is giving the error. Add a method in component and call it in your template and display it if name is presented in the object otherwise nothing.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of data">
    <li>{{checkForName(item)}}</li>       
</ul>
```

in .ts file

```
checkForName(item: any){
    return item.name != undefined ? item.name : null;
}
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Nope, this cannot happen. The `item` in iteration can **never** be `undefined`. Angular wouldn't even try to render an `item` if it doesn't exist ;)

Comment: @AJT_82 yes, item iteration can be never done if it is `undefined`. I will update my answer and thank u for suggestion :)

Comment: I don't see how your modified answer changes anything? The error message OP is getting is `"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".` meaning that according to that `item` is undefined, and that cannot happen **ever** inside the iteration. So the code OP is presenting is actually totally working code. OP must not be showing the "real" code, as with the code that is presented, that error message would never occur.

Comment: item is never going to be `undefined` we know that, if you observe the `array[2]` object value is just   `{ "age": 21 }` there is  no `name` variable in this object. while iterating through this angular trying to get the name attribute but it's not there so it's throwing the error. Maybe that's not `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` as OP said but there is definitely error regarding to his code.

Comment: It's just simply not possible. Yes, the name might **not** exist, but the `item` **does** exists, so it's not undefined!

Comment: Also it's bad practice to call functions from template, and what you are presenting doesn't change anything, it's the same. Maybe you should read up on how ngFor works and realize the scenario OP is presenting is never possible ;)

Comment: @AJT_82 check here, this is very much related to OP's Question. I hope you will get a good clarity about `ngFor`. Thank you ;)

Comment: What should I check?

Comment: And I just don't know how I can't explain this to you... look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbsajb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html That error cannot be thrown, no matter if it's asynchronous or not. Is a demo proof enough? :D (other array is with timeout)

Comment: if there would be more nested objecs like `item.something.name` THEN you would probably need the safe navigation operator. But in this case, there is not!

Comment: @AJT_82 now I understood something from your demo  about `ngIf`. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

If you have JSON in some variable, ensure your have a object variable with the name data:

```
export class yourclass {
  public data =[Your json array];
}
```

If your JSON is in a separate file, you may import it into the typescript file using:

```
import myjson from 'jsonfilepath/jsonfilename.json';
export class yourclass{
   public data = myjson;
}
```